# HTML5 Drag and Drop - prevent drop for one item

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am looking at this HTML5 demo of a bin that 'eats' anything in the list . I want to modify it to 'eat' only some of the items and others would be rejected.

The code is here: http://html5demos.com/drag

This code works in IE which is a requirement. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Being impatient I found a way to do this..

`<ul>
      <li><a draggable="true" id="one" href="#">one</a></li>
      <li><a draggable="true" href="#" id="three">two</a></li>
      <a draggable="true" href="#" id="trick">trick</a>
      <li><a draggable="true" href="#" id="four">four</a></li>
     <a draggable="true" href="#" id="five">five</a>
 </ul>`

The solution was to realise that I could add an extra tag within the list. I then had to style the  tag to look exactly the same as the list item. If the person tries to drag the trick item it doesn't disappear from the list and the bin doesn't provide a text response.